# Get MicrosoftAccount login from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-authentication, microsoft-account

I found some strange information in log for login auditing. I am using Windows authentication and there are 2 different entries for same user. Sometimes there is ComputerName\User and sometimes MicrosoftAccount\user@email.com. This two accounts are connected. How can i know which account will be used and when?

How can i extract MicrosoftAccount\user@email.com from SQL Server logins?
I am using this query but i am only getting ComputerName\User account with it

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN
        CHARINDEX('\', @@SERVERNAME) > 0
    THEN
        REPLACE(name, SUBSTRING(@@SERVERNAME, 1, CHARINDEX('\', @@SERVERNAME) - 1), CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS nvarchar(128)))
    ELSE
        REPLACE(name, @@SERVERNAME, CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS nvarchar(128)))
    END
AS name FROM sys.syslogins ORDER BY name
```

Comment: It looks like MicrosoftAccount\user@email.com is displayed when non-MS email is used for account